# On what domain the equation : $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}xy^4$ with the initial condition $y(0)=6$ is true.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On what domain the equation :

$y'=xy^4$  with the initial condition $y(0)=6$ is true.

My solution:

$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=xy^4 \implies \frac{dy}{y^4}=xdx\implies \int \frac{1}{y^4} dy=\int xdx \implies -\frac{1}{3y^3}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C \implies  C=-\frac{1}{648}.$

Then $y=(\frac{216}{-324x^2+1})^\frac{1}{3}$

I think the domain is $(\frac{-1}{324})^\frac{1}{3}<x<\infty $
I am not sure if the answer is $(\frac{-1}{324})^\frac{1}{3}$ or $(\frac{1}{324})^\frac{1}{3}$

Thank you !

Comment: I already addressed a very similar question you asked before, but again, the question is ill-formed. The domain in which you want the equation to be true must be specified separately. The equation does not have a unique domain of its own that you can "prove". For example, it is entirely possible to conceive of a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is not differentiable at $0$, but is differentiable everywhere else and satisfies the differential equation you provided everywhere else together with the initial condition.

Comment: The above situation characterizes a different class of functions than the situation in which you expect the solution to be differentiable everywhere and satisfies the equation you gave everywhere with the initial condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the solution a little more compactly as
$$
y(x)=\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{1-324x^2}}.
$$
The solution domain certainly will not contain the point where the denominator becomes zero,
$$
0=1-324x^2
$$
does not lead to a cube root of a negative number.

Comment: Sorry , I am not sure If i get it : 

$y(x)=\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{1-324x^2}} \implies  x\neq \pm\frac{1}{324}$

In addition $0\in I \implies$ the solution is $-\frac{1}{324}<x<+\frac{1}{324}$

Am I correct ?

Comment: There needs to be a square root in-between. Otherwise yes.